# Do all Oglaf comics share the same universe?

Tags: oglaf

We see some of the characters showing up in different story lines. The setting of most if not all comics seems some medieval / fantasy world.

But do all comics actually share this same world?

---

*This was prompted by the comic "Clumsy Fetish", which is NSFW, so I won't link to it. It **does** seem to take place in a slightly more modern world.*

Comment: I am so happy we have an Oglaf tag :'D

Comment: Heh, I re-read it looking for modern things. I never noticed bear trap until now ;)

Comment: Given the quote from the series' creator, is there anything else you'd like to see before considering an acceptance?

Comment: @I noticed you've bountied this due to "concerns". What were these concerns?

Comment: @Valorum standard wording, as you know. And you've asked the creator for further clarification. A statement by the author would be pretty canonical.

Answer (score 13):

Yes, probably, albeit within the constraints of the [rule of funny](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/RuleOfFunny), where things can happen outside the universe (such as the occasional worldwide sex-zombie apocalypse) without it affecting the main continuity.

Note that the creator, Bodil Bodilson consistently refers to it as the

> *Oglafverse*

in comments and [in his](https://twitter.com/Oglaf/status/719181081593786368) [various](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:tZzT4gTEaY0J:https://twitter.com/oglaf/status/686755949348917248%20&cd=3&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us) [twits](https://twitter.com/oglaf/status/643081588679376896)

Comment: The twits confirm the existence of an _Oglafverse_, but not that **all** episodes take place in it.

Comment: @sqb - Well, they can't all take place on the same world given that at least three of the episodes end with **the end of the world.** :-)

Comment: Well, the _Oglafverse_ may be reset between episodes. I'm not asking if they're all canonically consistent.

Comment: Fair enough. I've asked the creator for a clarification. In the absence of a further statement, I'm going to leave this one as-is.